# Setting field values of objects contained within arraylists java

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I am currently trying to set an object's int field value to a specific number. This object is contained within an `ArrayList`. I can't figure out how to set the value though.

Here is the object: (this object extends Unit, arrayLocation is the 0 on the far right)

```
Ranger rangerObj0 = new Ranger("Ranger", 100, 4, 10, unitInv0, 0);
```

here is the objects constructor for reference:

```
public Ranger(String name, int health, int moves, int dmg, ArrayList<Item> rangerInv, int arrayLocation) {
  super(name, health, moves, dmg, rangerInv, arrayLocation);
```

Here is the `ArryaList` that `rangerObj0` is contained in at 0:

```
ArrayList<Unit> playerUnits = new ArrayList<Unit>();
```

and here is what I am trying to do:

```
playerUnits.get(0).setInt(arrayLocation, 0);
```

I want to be able to set the arrayLocation field to any specific number I need  but I get this error when I try the above code:

```
arrayLocation cannot be resolved to a variable
```

What do I actually need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to set arrayLocation of the ranger to 0? If yes, I think you might be looking for this instead, playerUnits.get(0).setArrayLocation(0); That is assuming that your Ranger class has a set function called setArrayLocation though.

Comment: @DarthBusiness 
Which version of java you're using ?

Comment: This is ... just strange. Does `Ranger` has a `setInt` method ? and what is type of `arrayLocation` ? Did you declare it as a variable ? You're trying to set a field in an object generically ? Why dont you just have a setter for `arrayLocation` ? (I wonder where the upvote on this comes from)

Comment: @Ali Ben Zarrouk your right, so simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `playerUnits.get(0).setArrayLocation(0);`